# Facebook can't pick my blog image

Tags: facebook, jekyll

I have a blog built on jekyll and for example the post in this address - http://lourencoazevedo.com/2015/05/12/effortless.html, if I post it on facebook it doesn't display the picture - it doesn't pick it up.

I tried to put an html - code on the blog like:

```
<p align="center"><img src="http://lourencoazevedo.com/pimagens/2015-05-12.jpg" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; width: 800px"></p>
```

or creating a class **pic** in CSS like

```
<p class="pic"><img src="http://lourencoazevedo.com/pimagens/2015-05-12.jpg"><p>
```

Now I'm just using the standard jekyll notation

```
![germinado](http://lourencoazevedo.com/pimagens/2015-05-12.jpg)
```

which renders as

```
<p><img src="http://lourencoazevedo.com/pimagens/2015-05-12.jpg"
alt="germinado" /></p>
```

But none of this works.

Any help will be welcome - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Facebook which image to use with specific tags (which go in the head part of your HTML page).

For images these could be:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://your-image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:url" content="http://your-image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://your-image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
```

More information on [the Facebook documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices).

You can also use the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) (you need to log in) to test your tags and force Facebook to refresh their data.

Comment: Thanks - I could find this website - http://milanaryal.com/2015/integrating-social-meta-tags-into-jekyll/ and use the information there. Still can't get the image running - Although Facebook says that everything is ok, I can see the image there - if you can, try this address on FBK debugger - http://lourencoazevedo.com/2015/05/12/effortless.html - everything looks good but still can't pick up the image.

Comment: For some reason it started to work... thanks Luc for helping me to understand better this concept.